# Is possible to modify the url without reloading a page?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Into my application, at a certain point, I receive some query params form a callback. I need to store them onto redux store and after that redirect, the user on a page and I need to modify the URL without reloading the page.

Actually I'm using `history.replaceState`. It works but if I go on to another route (my internal routes) it concatenates the actual link to the actual(replaced)

Comment: Yes, I use it into my app for internal routing but once I go directly to a pat I lose the history and goBack or goForward. So I'm trying to find another solution.

Answer (score 2):

The code in function `reload` is static, i.e. it will execute only when you call it. If at the time of calling it, the window's width isn't more than 1000px, your function won't do anything.

You need to listen to the [`resize`](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) event instead:

```js
window.location.replace(window.location)
```

Comment: window.location.replace("index.html"); other wise you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using redux (using mobx) but i usualy use the code below to update the url without refreshing the the page.

This first part listens on the url from the second snippet `@computed get url()` and automatically updates the url when it changes.

```
autorun(() => {
    const path = store.navigation.url
    if (path !== window.location.pathname) {
        window.history.pushState(null, null, path)
    }
})
```

And this part is just to figure out what to put in the url ex: press a tab that chages the `@observable view: View = "home"` to `@observable view: View = "hooks"` the url will change from site.com to site.com/hooks

```
@observable view: View = "home"
......
@computed get url() {
        switch (this.view) {
            case "home":
                return '/'
            case "hooks":
                return 'hooks'
            case "fields":
                return "fields"
            case "validation":
                return 'validation'
            case "reusable":
                return 'reusable'
            case "profile":
                return 'profile'
            case "userProfile":
                return 'userProfile'
            case "review":
                return 'review'
        }
    }
```